# Electron version 12 error: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I've already configured `nodeIntegration`, `contextIsolation` and `enableRemoteModule` in main.js. But the following message still appears:

This error only happens when I try to import the lib.js file through the script.js.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './lib'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\sergi\Documents\Desenvolvimento\phoras\electron-quick-start\app\index.html
    at Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887)
    at Function.o._resolveFilename (electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:33)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5)
    at Function.o._load (electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:33)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88)
    at script.js:1
```

I am using the following version:

- Electron: v12.0.2
- NodeJS: v12.5.0
- NPM:  v6.9.0
- I'm using electron from that repository: [repository](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start)

Below are the files that I am using

app/**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="module" src="./js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app/js/**script.js**

```
const {lib} = require('./lib'); // this is where the error is happening

lib.message('hello');
```

app/js/**lib.js**

```
function message(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}
```

**main.js**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {

  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
    }    
  })
  mainWindow.loadFile('app/index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
  app.on('activate', function () {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```

What can I do to fix this error when trying to import lib.js?

Comment: Have you tried `require("./lib.js")`? Is `lib.js` in the same directory as `script.js`?

Comment: @Phil I tried it too, and it doesn't work

Comment: Also, `lib.js` doesn't appear to _export_ anything which might be why it doesn't appear as an import-able module

Comment: @Phill yes, they are in the same directory

Comment: I removed the type="module" from index.html and the error still persists

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Try this and export your function that way.
const message = () => {

};

export default message;
-------

import message from './lib.js'

If that will be working for you I will give you a cleaner way to do that

Comment: I did as you asked, but now this error is appearing: `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './lib.js' does not provide an export named 'default'` in the script.js:1 file

Comment: Try this 

lib method 
-----
export function square(x) {
    return x * x;
}

call that way --- 

import { square} from 'lib';
console.log(square(11)); 
-----

OR


------
import * as lib from 'lib';
console.log(lib.square(11));

Comment: @AzeemAslam now this message appears: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier" lib ". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../". `

Comment: @AzeemAslam Electron demanded a bar, I put it with the bar and this message appeared: `GET file: /// C: / lib net :: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: on which operating system you are
-----
try './lib'

-----
or we will use some path lib to get exact path

Comment: I'm using windows 10 professional x64

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/svelte-vekyrr?file=index.html
check this

Comment: I made: `import * as lib from './lib.js'; console.log(lib.square(11));` I now it worked !! =)

Comment: wallah congrats Happy coding plz accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this lib method

```
 export function square(x) { return x * x; }
```

call that way ---

```
import { square} from 'lib';
 console.log(square(11));
```

----- OR ------

```
import * as lib from 'lib';
 console.log(lib.square(11));
```

must read Module systems for JavaScript

Comment: read this It's a very import concept for JS dev
https://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html